# Interpretation in $R^{n}$ for complex eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, change-of-basis

So I have a 4x4 matrix from which I get 4 complex eigenvectors and I want to create a real basis for the eigenvectors. I know that for a  $2 \times 2 $matrix we can use:

$$\Lambda=V^{-1}AV$$

where $\Lambda$ is the real standard form of the $2 \times 2$ matrix, A and $V$ is the change of basis matrix.

I also know that for the $2 \times 2$ case, $V = [Re(v)|Im(v)]$ (by columns) where $v$ is an eigenvector associated with one of the eigenvalues.

My question is how does the formula for $V$ from the $2 \times 2$ matrix extend for a 4x4 matrix? Because if the same formula for $V$ is applied it will not yield a square matrix, thus, it will not have an inverse to compute $\Lambda$ from it.

Thank you,

Alex

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "create a real basis for the eigenvectors"

Comment: See [page 3 here](http://www.wright.edu/~chaocheng.huang/lecture/mth255/mth255lect13.pdf) for what I suspect that you are trying to do

Comment: Do you want to diagonalize $A$ ?

Comment: To change from complex basis to a real basis. Namely, to find the matrix $\Lambda$ which would yield real but equivalent eigenvectors. So $AV = V\Lambda$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I think page 3 does the job! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Consider a $4 \times 4$ real matrix $A$ with four distinct non-real eigenvalues $\alpha, \overline{\alpha}, \beta, \overline{\beta}$.  If $u$ is an eigenvector for $\alpha$, then its complex conjugate $\overline{u}$ is an eigenvector for $\overline{\alpha}$.  Similarly if $v$ is an eigenvector for $\beta$, $\overline{v}$ is an eigenvector for $\overline{\beta}$.  Then you can consider the basis
$$ \text{Re}(u), \text{Im}(u), \text{Re}(v), \text{Im}(v)$$
Note that $$\eqalign{A (\text{Re}(u)) &= \frac{1}{2} A (u + \overline{u}) \cr &= \frac{1}{2} \left(\alpha u + \overline{\alpha} \overline{u}\right)\cr &= \text{Re}(\alpha) \text{Re}(u) - \text{Im}(\alpha) \text{Im}(u)}$$
etc.